# Ionic 2 App loads on browser and Android, but not on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2

My team recently extended our supported platforms to iOS, and I still haven't been able to get it to run on any iOS devices. Using "ionic serve" and "ionic run android" works great, everything works as expected. But when using "ionic run ios", the app loads and goes to the classic White Screen of Death. No errors are logged, and nothing is displayed.

The page that does load (the white screen) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ionic</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

<link ios-href="build/css/app.ios.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link md-href="build/css/app.md.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link wp-href="build/css/app.wp.css" rel="stylesheet">  
</head>
<body class="platform-ios platform-cordova platform-webview">

<!-- this Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
<ion-app></ion-app>

<!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!-- Polyfill needed for platforms without Promise and Collection support -->
<script src="build/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<!-- Zone.js and Reflect-metadata  -->
<script src="build/js/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/zone.js"></script>
<!-- the bundle which is built from the app's source code -->
<script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried loading up the basic starter Ionic 2 app using the same commands and approach and it worked, and the page had content inside of it. From using some console.logs and the like I found that the code never loads the app.ts file, so that would explain why it never reaches the home page, but since no errors are logged I can't figure out where to even look at to fix anything. I'm wondering if something is wrong in the app.bundle.js, but I just don't really know where to start.

Has anyone ever had any similar issues?

My version info is as follows:

- Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.7
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
- ios-deploy version: 1.8.6
- ios-sim version: 5.0.8
- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
- Node Version: v6.2.0
- Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
- iPad mini 2 and iPhone 6 iOS version: 9.3.3

Comment: Most likely not actual. I recommend to run through XCode on a real device. There you should see the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it here, suddenly someone come in handy.

---

> It is necessary to correct the errors in the console is running ionic serve.
>   Otherwise, just do not compile the necessary file app/www/build/js/app.bundle.js

---

> For completeness, better run applications in production environments.
>   They are generally more informative than emulators.